# Which parameters will be chosen according to contour loss?

Tags: loss-functions

When we draw a contour for loss based on 2 or 3 parameters, we know that the loss is equal between two inner shape, but the parameters will be varied. So, which parameters in this inner shape give us a better generalization?

[image]

Comment: generalization and loss are two different things, if you just interpolate your points, you will have 0 loss, but a terrible generatlization

Comment: Yes, I know. But my question is another thing. Suppose that here in this graph, there are countless of combination of (w1,w2) that give us the loss of 0.08 according to above contour. So, which combination of parameter we should choose to have a better generalization? Can we find it anyway?

Comment: Again, loss and generalization are different things, if you have many points with the same loss, you can't know which offers the best generalization, you might have some guesses, for example using L1 and L2, but that's far from being always true... also, the points insider each "level" have not the same values, so the ellipse of 0.08 probably have a point with value 0.06 in the middle  or something like this